# Infinite propagation speed for the Schrodinger operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

Question related to:
[On the propagation of singularities in PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163864/on-the-propagation-of-singularities-in-pde) and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164277/hypoellipticity-and-singular-support.

in what sense is to interpret the sentence the schrodinger operator
has infinite propagation speed. And what about the fact that if
there is a singularity at $t=0$, then at $t=\epsilon$ there isn't
anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Schrodinger equation with an initial condition supported in a bounded region.  At any positive $t$, the wave function is nonzero arbitrarily far away.  In that sense, the particle can travel (albeit with small probability) at arbitrarily high speeds.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that explains very well the infinite speed. What about singularities? Is it true that if the initial condition is not smooth, the solution becomes smooth 'istantaneously'?

Comment: It may do so. Or it may start out smooth and then get a singularity at some later time.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of this behavior?